# Number of elements of order $p$ in a group $G$ and its factor group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

I’m wondering if there is a counterexample of the following statement.

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $G$ has an element of order $p$ (prime). Let the positive integer $n$ be the number of elements of order $p$.  Then $G/H$ has at most $n$ elements of order $p$.

I don’t know if it is true or not. 
I tried to prove it but I couldn’t

Can anyone help me to prove or disprove it?

Thank you

Comment: @Dieteich Burde Oh, yes it is a prime I will edit it

Comment: From the structure theorem on finitely generated abelian groups, you may write $G$ as a product of cyclic groups.

Comment: In fact you can reduce to the case when $G$ is a $p$-group and then it follows easily from $G$ being a direct product of cyclic $p$-groups. (By the way, there is no need at all to assume that $G/H$ has elements of order $p$, because the result is trivially true if it does not. Unnecessary assumptions are distracting!)

Comment: @Derek Holt Thanks for the comment! That’s what I tried to approach this. I considered the case when G is a p-group. And, by the structure theorem of a finitely generated abelian groups, G is a direct product of cyclic groups of order a power of p, which are in turn cyclic p-groups. But I don’t know what to do next. I also know $G/H$ is a p-group too. Thus $G/H$ is also a direct product of cyclic p-groups. I believe that the number of the direct summands of $G/H$ should be less than or equal to the number of direct summands of $G&. But I don’t know how to prove it

Comment: First, if the number of direct summands of $G$ is k, then G is generated by k elements, which implies that $G/H$ is generated by k elements. Then I guess it should follow somehow the number of direct summands of $G/H$ is less than or equal to k. But I’m stuck in here. Can you help me to prove it? If I prove it, then it’s clear that the number of elements of order p in $G$ is greater than or equal to that of $G/H$.

Comment: And I edited the statement. I changed the sentence to remove unnecessary assumptions. Thanks

Comment: The minimal size of a generating set of a direct product of $k$ (nontrivial) cyclic $p$-groups is $k$

Comment: @Derek Holt Oh, That’s exactly what I struggle to prove. Could you give me some hints for it?

Comment: This follows from the [Burnside Basis Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_basis_theorem)

Comment: Every subgroup H is the Frattini subgroup? I don’t see anything from this theorem. Could you explain it more in detail? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $G$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups of prime power order, we see that $n$ is just $p^k-1$ where $k$ is the number of summands whose order is a power of $p$.  This number $k$ can also be described as the dimension of $G/pG$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Now let $K=G/H$ and observe that the quotient map $G\to K$ induces a surjective homomorphism $G/pG\to K/pK$, and thus $\dim K/pK\leq\dim G/pG$.  That is, $K$ has at most $k$ summands whose order is a power of $p$, and thus also has at most $p^k-1$ elements of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks! I have never thought of vector spaces. I think it is a great proof! I’m wondering if we can prove it by using group theory.

Comment: Well, you don't really need to think of them as vector spaces--you can just say directly that $G/pG$ is a direct sum of $k$ cyclic groups of order $p$.  The vector space perspective is useful for generalizations, though (for instance, to make an analogous statement about modules over a PID instead of just abelian groups).

Comment: Umm maybe I don’t understand it well but how can we talk about the dimension of $G/pG$ without knowing a ring and a module?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  $G/pG$ is an abelian group of exponent $p$, and so it admits a unique $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space structure, where $n\cdot x$ is the sum of $n$ copies of $x$ for any integer $n$ (and this is well-defined where $n$ is taken mod $p$ since $G/pG$ has exponent $p$).

Comment: Umm, what I mean is that, without referring to linear algebra, module, field and ring, is it possible to prove it? I mean in your proof you used the fact that $G/pG$ has a vector space structure over a field of order p. I wonder if the statement can be proved by the elementary group theory. I do not know how to define ‘elementary’ though. Maybe group, subgroup, cyclic group, normality, quotient group, product group, free group, free product, free abelian group, structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, Sylow’s theorem, nilpotent group and etc.

Comment: With these, I tried to prove $K$ has at most $k$ summands whose order is a power of $p$. But I don’t know what to do without the dimension in your proof.

Comment: Ahhhhh!! Sorry for bothering you. I was fool. I think it was clear because a homomorphism $G/pG \to K/pK$ is surjective. So we don’t need to consider the dimensions of $G/pG$ and $K/pK$! If $|G/pG| = p^n$ then $|K/pK| > p^n$ is impossible since there is an epimorphism between them. Is this right?

Comment: Right, exactly, you can just use cardinality.